# Make two table column widths the same automatically

Tags: tables

I have this table, where the total width of the two columns (a) and (b) can vary depending on the text width of Figure X above it. How can I get (a) and (b) to each have the same width always? Also, I circled in red a problem where the vertical lines are not aligned?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rc|cc}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{Figure~\ref{fig:my_label} sub-plot}                                    \\ \hline
Variable             & Unit                 & (a)                          & (b)                          \\ \hline
One          & m             & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary & 50                           \\
Two              & kg                    & 0.5                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary \\
Three           & Hz                   & 1000                        & 1000                        
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I should add, the text in the red cells which says "Vary", that has a different meaning. It is not related to anything to do with the cell width.

Comment: For the problem of alignment make sure you zoom it 800% because usually is a little visual glitch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compute the width of the header, because when the total natural size of spanned columns doesn't fit the multicolumn entry, the excess space goes in the last spanned column.

Do this only if you find that there is a mismatch: otherwise you'll get wrong size.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 

\newlength{\templen}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{Just for the number}\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\settowidth{\templen}{Figure~\ref{fig:my_label} sub-plot}
\setlength{\templen}{\dimexpr(\templen-2\tabcolsep)/2}

\begin{tabular}{ r c | *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\templen}} }
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Figure~\ref{fig:my_label} sub-plot}                   \\
\hline
Variable & Unit & (a)                          & (b)                          \\
\hline
One      & m    & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary & 50                           \\
Two      & kg   & 0.5                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary \\
Three    & Hz   & 1000                         & 1000                        
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Use `\ref*` in `\settowidth` in case you're loading `hyperref`.

[image]

You don't need `\multicolumn` for empty cells. The misalignment was due to the fact that the rule has to be specified in the *preceding* column (exception: a starting rule).

Here's how I'd typeset the table.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{Just for the number}\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ @{} l c c c @{} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{Figure~\ref{fig:my_label} sub-plot} \\
\midrule
Variable & Unit & (a)                          & (b)                          \\
\midrule
One      & m    & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary & 50                           \\
Two      & kg   & 0.5                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary \\
Three    & Hz   & 1000                         & 1000                         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But probably the text in the first row should go in the caption to the table.

[image]

By the way, you don't need the figure and table go in different floats: a `tabular` can very well go in a `figure` environment. Something like the following might do.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\hspace*{\fill}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{tabular}[b]{ @{} l c c c @{} }
\toprule
Variable & Unit & (a)                          & (b)                          \\
\midrule
One      & m    & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary & 50                           \\
Two      & kg   & 0.5                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary \\
Three    & Hz   & 1000                         & 1000                         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\hspace*{\fill}

\caption{This is the image of a duck, with data next to it.}\label{fig:my_label}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To have the last two columns occupy the same width automatically, use the `X` column specification from `tabularx` for them. To further center their content, just modify `X` by adding `>{\centering\arraybackslash}X`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{.6\linewidth}{rc| *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} }
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Figure~\ref{fig:my_label} sub-plot}    \\ \hline
            Variable &         Unit          & (a)                          & (b)                          \\ \hline
                 One &           m           & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary & 50                           \\
                 Two &          kg           & 0.5                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary \\
               Three &          Hz           & 1000                         & 1000
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, can the (a) and (b) columns be centered?

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

complete automatically is (to my opinion) to complicated, since it depend from cells contents. this means, that you need to measure all contents and from them select the widest and to this adopt all columns width or determine table width and using `tabularx` table environment.

simpler is estimate the width of the widest cell (by counting number of characters) and then use this width in `p{...}` column type accordingly modified:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}p{3em}
                >{\centering}p{3em} |
           *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}}
                }
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Figure~\ref{fig:my_label} sub-plot}        \\ \hline
Variable    & Unit      & (a)                           & (b)                           \\ \hline
One         & m         & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary  & 50                            \\
Two         & kg        & 0.5                           & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}Vary  \\
Three       & Hz        & 1000                          & 1000
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```